# IS Google ignoring white text with dark background?

Tags: seo

My Website iascoachingindia.in have some coloured boxes with white text on, however background colour is dark and clearly visible to human eye, but I felt Google proffered text which is black in text with white background.

Please anybody have some experienced in the same??

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Future non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se].

Answer (score 0):

Google can crawl and index all the fonts and color, but the most important thing is to avoid make it spammy by adding the same font color with the same background color.

Also if its with the same color, still Google can access them and index them but you will get a penalty.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but my query was, is google ignoring or not, I know google can index the text with zero size, I mean google giving priority to my white background text, Because it shows text on SERP, seems most relevant and ignored the others coloured boxes, I checked with multiple search queries.

Comment: Google see all the text without colors if you are adding the colors using CSS, color and font size didn't matter at all.